# Conditionally show button in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that performs a pagination feature with blog posts. Each time the "load more" button is clicked, five more posts are loaded to the bottom of the page. I am drawing a blank right now on how to solve an issue with it though.

**The Problem:**

Once the "load more" button is clicked and all of the available posts are visible, the "load more" button should go away.

**The Code:**

```
const Posts = ({ state }) => {
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
  const [categoryId, setCategoryId] = useState();
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]); // Posts for each category
  const [allPosts, setAllPosts] = useState([]); // All posts from all categories

  // Get all of the available categories
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(state.source.api + "/wp/v2/categories")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        setCategories(data);
      })
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (categoryId) {
      fetch(state.source.api + "/wp/v2/posts?categories=" + categoryId + "&per_page=5")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          setPosts(data);
        });
    }
  }, [categoryId]);

  // Get posts for each category
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!categoryId) {
      return;
    }
    let url = state.source.api + "/wp/v2/posts?categories=" + categoryId + "&per_page=5";
    if (page > 1) {
      url += `&page=${page}`;
    }
    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setPosts([...posts, ...data]);
      });
  }, [categoryId, page]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let url = state.source.api + "/wp/v2/posts?per_page=5";
    if (page > 1) {
      url += `&page=${page}`;
    }
    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setAllPosts([...allPosts, ...data]);
      });
  }, [page]);

  // Add View All button to category buttons array
  const allCategories = categories.map((category, i) => (category))
  allCategories.push("View All");

  return (
    <>
      {allCategories.map((category, i) => {
        return (
          (category === "View All") ? (
            <button onClick={() => { setPosts([]) }}>View All</button>
          ) : (
              <button className="btn" key={i} onClick={() => {
                setPage(1);
                setPosts([]);
                setCategoryId(category.id);
              }}>{category.name}</button>
            )
        )
      })}

      <div>
        {posts.length === 0 ? (
          <>
            {allPosts.map((allPost, i) => {
              return (
                <li key={i}>{allPost.title.rendered}</li>
              )
            })}
            <button onClick={() => { setPage(page + 1); }}>Load more</button>
          </>
        ) : (
            <>
              <ol>
                {posts.map((post, i) => {
                  return (
                    <li key={i}>{post.title.rendered}</li>
                  )
                })}
              </ol>

              <button onClick={() => { setPage(page + 1); }}>Load more</button>
            </>
          )}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Say there are a maximum of 3 pages worth of posts, five being viewed at a time - so 15 posts total... once all 3 pages are visible, and I click "load more" again (even though no more posts are available), I get a console error that `... my api... GET /wp/v2/posts?categories=78&per_page=5&page=4 400 (Bad Request)`, which obviously means that there was no page 4 to fetch because there are no more posts.

I think this requires an if statement, but I am not sure how I would get started writing it. Does anyone have any input?

Comment: Your response from the API needs to include the total number of pages for your pagination parameters. When that value is equal to the current page, then don't show the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a variable called totalPages, which hold the number of pages, and then compare between totalPages and page states, something like that:

```
{page <= totalPages && <button onClick={() => { setPage(page + 1); }}>Load more</button>}
```

in this case if page is 3 and totalPages is 4 the button will not display

Answer (score 0):

Try an npm package called "react-paginate", with this you can easily implement the pagination logic without messing up with the code, and here is the link for this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-paginate
Just go with the documentation and you can figure out how to do this, but if you face any problem then don't hesitate, just ask me.